# URL - Drill through report not running with parameters

Tags: javascript, reporting-services, drillthrough

I've two reports A and B, which I’m trying to get to run via the URL. I can get the report to open (from the URL), but it doesn't run (with the parameters), the user has to select the parameters again. Both reports use the same parameters BTW.

The URL is built with this expression

```
="javascript:void(window.open('http://reportssrv/Reports/Pages/Report.aspx?ItemPath=%2fReports+In+Progress%2fReportToRun&rs:Command=Render&Territory="& Parameters!Territory.Value &"&CCG="& Parameters!CCG.Value &"&PracticeCode="& Parameters!PracticeCode.Value &"'))"
```

This generates the following url

```
    http://reportssrv/Reports/Pages/Report.aspx?ItemPath=/Reports+In+Progress/ReportToRun&rs:Command=Render&Territory=27&CCG=01C&PracticeCode=N81632
```

This opens up nicely in the browser (IE) but the report is sat at the default load (nothing selected nor has the report ran). If I set the action to “go to report” it works, but I want to go down the URL route. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: What is ItemPath? Shouldn't it be just Report.aspx?/Reports In Progress/ReportToRun&rs:Command=Render...

Comment: Hi, I did try that before, but get **A required argument is missing from the URL that opens this page: ItemPath.** when IE goes to the URL.